# Linear space, two subspaces, conclusions.

Tags: linear-algebra

$X$ is linear space, $U,V$ are subspaces of $X$.  Then:
**a.** $\dim U + \dim V \le n$
**b.** subset $U\cap V$ is linear subspace in $X$.
**c.** subset $T=\{u+v:u\in U, v\in V\}$ is linear subspace  of $X$.
**My approach:**
**a.** is not true, for example $U=V=X$. Then, $\dim U + \dim V = 2n > n$.
**c.** is true.  Let consider $at$ where $t\in T$.  $at=a(u+v)=au+av = u'+v' \in T$, where $u,u\in U, v,v'\in V$.
And last conditon to check:  $t_1+t_2 = (u_1+v_1)+(u_2+v_2)=(u_1+u_2)+(v_1+v_2) = u'+v'\in T$, where $u_1,u_2,u'\in U, v_1,v_2,v'\in V $
**b.** I guess that it is true, but I can't explain it.

Can you check **a., c.** and help me with **b.** ?

Comment: What have you thought about for B? Think of the simplest cases and try to extend them (maybe pictures).

Comment: Firstly, what about **a** and **c** ?

Comment: Your responses for A and C are right (in fact, C is a statement about the direct sum of subspaces which is itself a subspace). I didn't mention it at first because I had no issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your (a)-(c) are correct, and (b) is perhaps the easiest one:

$$0\in U\,,\,0\in V\implies 0\in U\cap V$$

$$x,y\in U\cap V\implies x,y \in U (\text{ and also}\;\in V)\implies ax+by\in U (\text{ and}\;V)...\text{and etc.}$$

with $\;a,b\in F=\;%$ the field over which the linear spaces are defined.

Comment: so **b.** is true. thanks :)